# Inline attachments in ROR 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inline, attachment, ruby-on-rails-2

I can find that attachments.inline can be used to render inline attachments in email but i am unable to do that as we are using rails 2.3.8. Is there a way by which I can still do this? I badly want this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, found my precious. This worked for me big time.

http://shortround.net/2010/11/24/multipart-alternative-multipart-related-email-with-actionmailer/

Answer (score 0):

[This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356924/rails-attachments-inline-are-not-shown-correctly-in-gmail) [or you can try this one](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)

Comment: hi @Newbie, Thank you for the solution. Both of them are working versions provided we use Rails 3. I am trying to figure out a way to do this in rails 2.3.8.

Comment: [Maybe this one might help](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-multipart-emails-with-attachments)

It use  ruby on rails v2.3.8

Comment: this is helpful for sending attachments. But in my case I want the attachments to be inline. Something like attachments.inline in rails 3

Comment: Why don't you just upgrade your Rails into Rails 3?

Comment: If I Was able to do that, I would have done that. I can't do it as of now.