# Rails inline mail attachments not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I am using ActionMailer to send an inline image. The user_mailer.rb file looks like this:

```
def welcome_mail(user, mail_content, subject) 
  @user = user 
  @mail_content = mail_content.html_safe 
  attachments.inline['orglogo.png'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/orglogo.png") 
  mail(:to => ["testuser@domain.com"],:Subject => subject) 
end
```

And the view contains:

```
<%= image_tag attachments['orglogo.png'].url %>
```

The image isn't appearing in the mail. This is how it appears in the mail client. I have tested on Outlook and Hotmail.

[image: Inline attachment]

Comment: Just to be clear. I did my homework before posting this. The solution mentioned here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356924/rails-attachments-inline-are-not-shown-correctly-in-gmail, does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution or rather workaround that worked was to upgrade to Rails 4. I am able to send  inline images without any problem in Rails 4.

Answer (score 2):

In my production app we are sending inline image using the above method and for me everything is working very fine for me. So i created the public gist for that working snippet of code. Please see if it helps you. 
Gist[Public gist with mailers](https://gist.github.com/vparihar01/5591510)

If doesn't work please try to paste your development.log here.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this Vivek. I had tried specifying the MIME types for the inline images. However no change. The image appears broken. No errors are generated in the development.log file.