# Unable to render inline attachments in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm trying to render inline images in a standard ActionMailer view using the approach outlined here [Rails attachments inline are not shown correctly in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356924/rails-attachments-inline-are-not-shown-correctly-in-gmail).

My code in my mailer:

```
attachments.inline["sample.png"] = {
  mime_type: "image/png",
  encoding: "base64",   # Including this line causes byte sequence error
  data: File.read('public/sample.png')
}
```

In mail view:

```
image_tag(attachments["sample.png"].url)
```

Gives the familiar ruby UTF-8 byte sequence error:

`invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`

To get around this I tried the following:

```
attachments.inline["logo.png"] = {
      mime_type: "image/png",
      data: Base64.encode64(File.read('public/logo.png')) 
    }
```

and also

```
attachments.inline["logo.png"] = File.read('public/logo.png')
```

Using the same `image_tag` syntax shown above.

Both of these resolve the UTF error, but I'm left with this nonsensical URL in the view:

`<img src="cid:5707a64ededbc_7bd83ffd648601e029875@localhostname.mail">`

The PNG image is valid and renders properly in a standard HTML view. I'm using Rails 4.2.5 with Ruby 2.2.4

**EDIT**

This works:

Mailer:

```
attachments.inline["cape.png"] = {
  mime_type: "image/png",
  # encoding: "base64",
  content: Base64.encode64(File.read(Rails.root.join("public/", "cape.png")))
}
```

View:

```
= image_tag "data:image/png;base64,#{attachments['logo.png'].read}"
```

Very awkward, however, and I'm still wondering why the conventional approach doesn't work.

Comment: add `Rails.root_path` before image url.

Comment: Thanks, tried that. It's able to find the image fine so adding `Rails.root` doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: try adding your live server url before image path

Comment: No change. Although inspecting the `attachments.inline["logo.png"]` object shows that `Content-ID: <5707ade638337_7bd83ffd648601e0346d1@localhostname.mail>` which is the same content as what `attachments.inline[logo.png].url` gives.

Comment: Encountered the same issue. Thanks for your solution! However, I feel myself frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I use only

```
attachments.inline["logo.png"] = File.read('public/logo.png')
```

It works fine for me

Comment: Thanks, already tried that but as I explained in my question above the URL doesn't display correctly in the `image_tag`.